# Remove whitespace indicators in Visual Studio Editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, settings

As the pic .

[image: Dots]

How can I delete the dots? I have reset to the default setting of VS, but doesn`t work.

Comment: I doubt there was no result on google for this.

Comment: @ssb yes, the question is the same, but I have google lots of times, and not  see that link....

Comment: @Evoque who knows? for me it's the first result if I google "visual studio dots"

Comment: @ssb yes, If  search so, it`s the first result. but before I think it`s some theme setting problem, so the search is "vs theme......", Of course I can`t get the right link and answer.

Comment: @Evoque: You can select an answer as the if any of below answers helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Edit | Advanced | View Whitespace

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you may be looking for

Go to:
Edit->Advanced->View White Space (CTRL+E,S)

Comment: Actually you get an up-vote too because your keyboard shortcuts seem to match mine :)